# LdapContext socket closed exception when server url is up and running

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ldap, jndi

I cannot tell if its a credentials/SSL issue or an LDAP configuration issue on the server. I tried accessing the local version and i had no problem (then again local Ldap and server setup is a little different). The socket is definitely not closed as we are using that url in our processing system and it is not down.

Code is failing at this line:

```
NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search("dc=barney,dc=com", "(objectclass=person)", getSimpleSearchControls());
```

Code block:

```
final String ldapAdServer = "ldap://myspecialhost.barney.us:389";                               
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapAdServer);    
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            ctx.setRequestControls(null);
   NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search("dc=barney,dc=com", "(objectclass=person)", getSimpleSearchControls());
```

And the stacktrace is here:

```
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: tiffany.barney.ca:389; socket closed; remaining name 'dc=barney,dc=com'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:437)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getSearchReply(LdapClient.java:613)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.search(LdapClient.java:536)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.doSearch(LdapCtx.java:1965)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1827)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1752)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:368)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:338)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:321)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:248)
    at com.barney.shopping.tiffany.LDAPImpTest.main(LDAPImplTest.java:154)
```

EDIT 1:
I tried using a different url and i get a connection timed out. Does this new url seem *more right* and i'm getting closer to the correct url perhaps?

EDIT 2:

new stacktrace

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: possibleURL:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:209)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:116)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1582)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2678)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:296)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:134)
    at blablalbla.LDAPInterfaceTest.main(LDAPInterfaceTest.java:154)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:351)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:186)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Show more code. Where you create the context ?

Comment: added more code with relevant block.

Comment: Is the Server `tiffany.barney.ca` reachable on port 123?

Comment: The LDAP port is 389, not 123. 'Socket closed' seems to be an advisory message: it refers to the local *socket,* not the *port,* and has nothing to do with whether the URL is available. However the `ServiceUnavailable' part does suggest the service isn't there at that URL.

Comment: @EJP yup i used `123` as an illustration, will edit the code to reflect that

Comment: 'Connection timed out' or 'Connect timed out'? They're not the same. Latter means a network connectivity problem.

Comment: @EJP the exact stacktrace is uploaded. `"Connection - timed out: connect"`